# 405 when posting Caliper results online

Tags: caliper

I checked out the latest version of caliper and ran a few benchmarks. The result are generated (as json) just fine, but upload to the microbenchmarks appengine website fails with:

POST http://microbenchmarks.appspot.com .... returned a response status of 405 Method Not Allowed

This issue has been raised with the Caliper team already:
https://code.google.com/p/caliper/issues/detail?id=220

... but was closed as "invalid". So I assume there is an alternative way to upload results ?

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of the webapp is going through some final code reviews right now.  It should arrive within the next few days.

UPDATE: The new version of the webapp has been deployed.  Everything should be working now.

Comment: Also, we apologize that you've been inconvenienced. We _believe_ that when we are through this horrible transition, you will eventually come to feel it was worth it! <cross fingers>